# Firebase addChildEventListener doesn't work in ListView android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple listview app and 1 data inside it

```
"1614156499206": {
  "title": "This is title",
  "description": "This is description",
  "date": "24 February 2021",
  "timestamp": "1614156499206"
}
```

And this is the Java code

```
...

TextAdapter textAdapter = new TextAdapter(getContext(), arrayList);
ArrayList<TextHelperClass> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
TextListView.setAdapter(TextAdapter);

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("text").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        for (DataSnapshot timestamp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            TextHelperClass textHelperClass = new TextHelperClass();
            String title = timestamp.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            String date = timestamp.child("date").getValue(String.class);
            String description = timestamp.child("description").getValue(String.class);
            String times = timestamp.child("timestamp").getValue(String.class);

            textHelperClass.setTitle(title);
            textHelperClass.setDate(date);
            textHelperClass.setDescription(description);
            textHelperClass.setTimestamp(times);
            arrayList.add(textHelperClass);
        }
        textAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        textAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

There's no error in the code, but when I run it, this is the output:

[image: output]

And when I change addChildEventListener to addValueEventListener, it works fine. What is the problem in my code when I use addChildEventListener? and how to refresh the listview everytime I delete the child?

```
textListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialog)
                .setMessage("Are you sure want to delete this text?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String time = arrayList.get(position).getTimestamp();
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("text").child(time).removeValue();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a `ValueEventListener` to a path, its `onDataChange` gets called with a snapshot of all data at that path at once. So if there are multiple child nodes under that path, you need to loop over `snapshot.getChildren()` to get to the each child node.

When add a `ChildEventListener` to the same path, its `onChildAdded` is called once for each individual child node. So you no longer need to loop over `snapshot.getChildren()`.

So my guess is that you need to get rid of the loop on your `onChildAdded`:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("text").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot timestamp, @Nullable String s) {
        TextHelperClass textHelperClass = new TextHelperClass();
        String title = timestamp.child("title").getValue(String.class);
        ...
        textAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```